# No ClassTag available despite ClassTag defined

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, scala-breeze

I have the following code:

```
trait MyTrait[B] {
  def func()
}

class A[B: ClassTag : Zero](val x: SparseVector[B]) extends MyTrait[B] {
  def this(x: Seq[(Int,B)]) = this({
    val (index, vals) = x.unzip
    vals.toArray
    new SparseVector[B](index.toArray, vals.toArray, vals.length)
  })

  def func(): Unit = {}
}
```

And get a `error: No ClassTag available for B` despite the fact that a ClassTag has been added to the generic parameter. What am I missing?

Above SparseVector is a member of the breeze linear algebra package (`breeze.linalg`)

Comment: `import scala.reflect.ClassTag` ?

Comment: Well, that compiles for me just fine if I define `MyTrait`.

Comment: The code is working fine (removing the unknown `extends MyTrait[B]`), is the error raised in the trait code?

Comment: I oversimplified my example. Please see updated version above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that context bounds (which are just desugared as implicit parameters), aren't applied to auxiliary constructors. You'll need to explicitly (hah) declare the parameter list:

```
def this(x: Seq[(Int,B)])(implicit z: Zero[B], ct: ClassTag[B]) = ...
```

This feels like a bug in the compiler, but I could see it argued both ways.